# ajax timeout only works for 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hi i have an ajax call and the timeout error that only works if the timeout is set to 1000 if i change this value to 5000 for example it gets ignored and then the error event wont fire

```
 $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',            
    url: raspberry_url+'/stop_training',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('token')},
    complete: function(data) {
        localStorage.setItem('SmartSailing',true);
        data = JSON.stringify(data.responseJSON);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if (data.status == '200'){
            localStorage.setItem('token',data.new_token);

        }else{
            mui.viewport.showPage("try-again-page", "FADE");
        }
    }, 
    timeout: 5000,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        localStorage.setItem('SmartSailing',false);
        if(textStatus==="timeout") {
            swal({
                title: "Connection Failed!",
                text: "Please check your connection to the SmartSailing network",
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "OK",
                closeOnConfirm: true, 
            });
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: Any relation to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099457/ajax-timeout-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Manage to solve the problem. The thing was that I try to make an ajax request to a server, but the server was down, it seems that the ajax request reaches the server but returns with an error. Its different when i try to request to another IP which doesnt exists in my network and the request doesnt "find where to go" so that is when the timeout takes place.